Minimum size for a planet to have a molten core
What would be the minimum size for a planet or moon so that it would have a molten core? Gravity and density would play a part but how could this be worked out?

Planets have a molten core because during their formation, parts of a star's accretion disk collide with enough kinetic energy to melt them. Over time, the cores gradually cool down until they are no longer molten. this has already happened inside Mars, for example.

This also likely depends quite a bit on what the core is made of.

Size is a factor, but time since forming, distance from their host star, surface texture and colour (albedo), chemical composition of the atmosphere, crust and core and the presence of radioactive materials are also important factors.
The surface area of a planet is proportional to its radius squared, while its volume and mass are proportional to radius cubed, so a large planet will tend to cool slower than a smaller planet.
How far they are from their host star determines how much external energy they receive from it, so all else being equal, a planet nearer its host star will cool slower than one that is further away.
Surface texture and colour is important because a dark surface will tend to radiate heat energy faster than other colours. A white surface will tend to reflect incoming heat energy from the parent star but also will be a less efficient "black body" so its radiates internal energy slower and these two effects tend to counteract and compete with each other.
The type of atmosphere is important due the greenhouse effect which can provide an insulation layer that slows the cool down and traps incoming radiation from the host star. The greenhouse effect is largely dependent on the chemical constituents of the gases that make up the atmosphere and partly dependent on the thickness and density of the atmosphere. A larger planet like Earth is likely to have a thicker denser atmosphere that traps more heat than a planet like Mars which has a thinner less dense atmosphere due to its lower mass and gravity not being able to retain a large or dense atmosphere. It's also possible that a planet that is very close to its host star will have its atmosphere stripped by stellar winds.
The presence of radioactive materials will also provide a heat input to the system also slowing down the cool down process.
The constituent elements of the core will play a part in determining whether or not the core is molten because different chemicals have different melting points. For example, it was thought the core of Mercury would be too cold to be molten but recent measurements suggest it is in fact molten and this is thought to be due to the presence of sulfur in the core which has a low melting point.
The chemical composition of the crust and mantle is important because some materials conduct heat faster than others. If the surface materials have low thermal conductance, they will insulate the core from the surface and greatly slow down its cool down and keep it molten for longer.
Overall, time is probably one of the most important factors. A newly formed small planet is likely to be much hotter than a large planet that has been around for a very long time.
P.S. Just thought of another. The presence of a large and close Moon or binary planet, could make a difference due to tidal effects, causing internal friction and thereby adding heat energy to the system.
As you can see it would be very hard to define a minimum size for a planet to be molten, because there are so many variables.
